# dynamic element @ViewChild

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For static element, viewchild is pretty stratightforward:

```
<myChildComponent #childId></myChildComponent>
```

and you can access it via:

```
@ViewChild('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
```

I would like to create elements dynamically.

For instance, I would like to create

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">
   <myChildComponent #user.name></myChildComponent>
</li>
```

so I don't know how many myCHildCOmponent I would have in advanced. it depends on how much would it return on ajax call. How do i access the component using viewchild? Thx

Comment: Why or for what purpose do you want to access the components? It's usually not a great idea to do that.

Comment: I just want to create the component dynamically through loops based on how many components that I get in returned from my ajax call. why is it not a good idea? thx

Comment: That doesn't say anything about why you want to access the component. Because this is not how Angular is supposed to be used. In Angular you usually modify the model and let components, directives, and bindings do the rest.

Comment: you can always use `@ViewChildren('#user')` but I agree with @Günter Zöchbauer it's not always the best idea

Comment: with @ViewChildren('#user'), i can't access the component that i want since i am going to have multiple myChildComponent with different name dependeing on the user.name passed. 

I have a dynamic form. I would like to call the server and return me with a list of objects which contains how many text boxes, radio button, images, and other elements. and this objects would be bound to a particular type of components which would render the form automatically.  I have control how this object would behave in myCHildComponent.